# ANDROID :How to start an existing activity as new activity from stack

Tags: android, activitygroup

I am using ActivityGroup in my application. I am starting each activity by :

```
     Window objWindow   = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(argActivityId,argIntent); 
     View objView   = objWindow.getDecorView();
     setContentView(objView);
```

But when I am trying to start an activity, that is already started by another activity, it will not start as a new activity, instead the old activity object is retained.

How can I start this as a new activity?

Thanking you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) intent flag of argIntent before calling startActivity.